# Spring Boot Caching at server startup

Tags: spring-boot, caching, spring-data-jpa

I found so many references about Spring Boot Caching.

I am able to implement at Repository method level.

```
@Cacheable(value = "booksByCategory", key = "#p0.categoryId", unless = "#result == null")
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = { "category" })
List<Book> findAllByCategoryId(Category category);
```

I would like cache the data at server startup instead of on first request.
How to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to "pre-load" your cache you could call findAllByCategoryId(category) for each expected category in a @PostConstruct method for the class that contains this method; e.g.:

```
@PostContstruct
void initCache() {
proxyRefToThisBean.findAllByCategoryId(cat1);
proxyRefToThisBean.findAllByCategoryId(cat2);
...
}
```

A method annotated with PostConstruct will be called during startup when your dependencies are being initialized.